# Stripe gateway rejecting live payments, thinking it’s in test mode

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to test my Stripe account with a live payment using my own debit card, but even though the toggle on my homepage dashboard is pointing to "Live", I get the following error on my site:

> "Your card was declined. Your request was in test mode, but used a non test card. For a list of valid test cards, visit: https://stripe.com/docs/testing."

Dummy test numbers work ok in either mode, but it just keeps thinking it’s in test mode. I’ve checked the test and live API keys and they are correct, having re-entered them several times with no change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The toggle you see on your dashboard doesn't actually affect your ability to create charges in test mode or live mode, it just changes the view on the dashboard.

You can always use both test mode and live mode, no matter what that toggle is set to. This is done by specifying which set of API keys you're using to make a charge: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I'm using Opencart for my site, which requires both test and live keys in order to run the Stripe gateway. If it's not the tab on the dashboard which determines which mode to be on, what control is?

Comment: Your plugin probably has its own way of switching between test and live modes then. I'm not familiar with Opencart, so I recommend you reach out to the plugin's authors or maintainers.